# Next steps to do with the mfccs, in voice recognition web based

Tags: javascript, voice-recognition, mfcc

I am working on urdu (language spoken in pakistan, india, bangladesh) voice recognition to translate urdu speech into urdu words. So far i did nothing but just have found meyda javascript library for extracting mfccs from data frames. Some document says that for ASR there needs first 12 or 13 mfccs out of 26. During the test, i have separate 46 phonemes(/b/, /g/, /d/ ...) in a folder in wav extension. After running meyda proccess on one of the phoneme, it creates 4 to 5 frames per phoneme, where each frame contain the mfccs each of first 12 values. Due to less than 10 reputation, post images are disabled. but you can the image on the following link. The image contain 7 frames of phoneme /b/. each frame includes 13 mfccs. The Red long vertical line value is 438, others or 48, 38 etc.
http://realnfo.com/images/b.png

My question is that whether i need to save these frames(mfccs) in the database as predefined phoneme for /b/ and the same i do for all the other phonemes and then tie the microphone, meyda will extract the mfccs per frame, and i will programmed the javascript that the extracted frame mfcc will be matched with the predefined frames mfccs by using Dynamic Time Warping. And at the end will get the smallest distance for specific phoneme.

The proffesional way after mfccs are HMM and GMM but i dont know how to deal with. i studied so many documents about HMM and GMM but waste.

Answer (score 2):

co-author of Meyda here.

That seems like a pretty difficult use case. If you already know how to split the buffers up into phonemes, you can run the MFCC extraction on those buffers, and use [k Nearest Neighbour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) (or some better classification algorithm) for what I would imagine would be reasonable success rate.

A rough sketch:

```js
const Meyda = require('meyda');
// I can't find a real KNN library because npm is down.
// I'm just using this as a placeholder for a real one.
const knn = require('knn');
// dataset should be a collection of labelled mfcc sets
const nearestPhoneme = knn(dataset);
const buffer = [...]; // a buffer containing a phoneme
let nearestPhonemes = []; // an array to store your phoneme matches
for(let i = 0; i < buffer.length; i += Meyda.bufferSize) {
  nearestPhonemes.push(nearestPhoneme(Meyda.extract('mfcc', buffer)));
}
```

After this for loop, nearestPhonemes contains an array of the best guesses for phonemes for each frame of the audio. You could then pick the most commonly occurring phoneme in that array (the mode). I would also imagine that averaging the mfccs across the whole frame may yield a more robust result. It's certainly something you'll have to play around with and experiment with to find the most optimal solution.

Hope that helps! If you open source your code, I would love to see it.

Comment: Co-author #2 here. Just adding that if you haven't already, you should pull the latest as we improved the MFCC implementation. Also, you might want to try and ask at http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ as they might have more advice for you.